# Low RAM in Debian/Ubuntu causes complete hang with disk thrashing

Tags: linux, hard-drive, memory, performance, swap

I've been having this severe performance issue, both in Ubuntu 11.10, and Debian Wheezy:

If one process uses up a great deal of RAM (say, 3700 MB out of 3900 MB), the system quickly becomes unusable, with constant disk thrashing. It gets to the point where the window manager doesn't respond, and killing the offending process takes several minutes. (Actually getting to a terminal, issuing pkill, waiting a while longer until the signal actually gets through)

This problem occurs even if the swap partition is completely disabled.

Investigating with iotop, it looks like most of the disk activity is disk read, going to processes such as google chrome, and the X window renderer. However, this is only limited information, as iotop no longer updates while the system is in full-thrash mode.

---

My question is:

1) what is causing the massive disk read?
2) how can I prevent this from making the system unusable?

Comment: Don't disable swap. That will force the system to keep all dirty pages in memory, making the problem *much* worse. Tell us more about your outer problem. Why is a process using so much memory? Is it because it's broken? Is it malicious?

Comment: I've run into the problem in a few different ways. sometimes opening up too many chrome tabs will trigger it, sometimes trying to cache 1M+ data structures in a python script will cause it. Running make with -j of 6 or 7 on something like the Boost libs will eat up memory pretty reliably, and then leave me thrashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system is moving data in RAM in and out of the hard drive to make way for other data in RAM.  Disk operations are far slower than RAM operations, causing the system to slow down significantly.  When your system is running out of physical memory, the system does this to expand the amount of "virtual" memory available, at the cost of performance.  This condition is called [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).

Unfortunately, the only full solution to this problem is to add more RAM.  Memory modules are relatively inexpensive; if you are consistently reaching the limits of available physical memory, you should add memory to your computer.

**Edit:** Because your system is low on physical memory, programs need to read from the hard drive more often, because free space in RAM is normally used to store files frequently or recently accessed to reduce disk reading.  With low free RAM, fewer files can be cached, reducing performance.  This is especially the case with applications like Chrome, which is quite memory- and I/O-intensive.  Once again, adding RAM will increase performance.  For more information on caching, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29).

Comment: The problem occurs even if I completely disable a swap partition. Also, I don't think simply more RAM will help, since the problem tends to occur with degenerate programs (some of which are written by me) using up arbitrary amounts of memory.

Comment: Some system process may be blocking normal I/O operations in applications such as Chrome.  In this case, it appears the OOM killer is attempting to kill processes using abnormal amounts of memory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand this comment. The I/O isn't blocked - Chrome, and X, and other random processes, are doing a lot of disk reading. No processes are killed by the Out of Memory killer, since the memory's not actually _full_, just nearly full. If the OOM would at least kill the offending process, it wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: Free memory is also used for caching files recently or frequently accessed; read my edit.

Comment: This answer most clearly describes what's going on, so I'm accepting it. Any ideas on 2)? Simply adding more RAM isn't always an option (especially if you've maxed out the RAM on a laptop). Low memory situations happen in life, how can Linux be made to not become unusable in those situations? i.e., if I've only got 200MB free, I don't *care* about rendering chrome, I just want to switch to a terminal and kill some processes.

Comment: You could use a USB flash drive and dedicate it to swap space.  Buy a high-speed flash drive (at least 4 GB), create a swap partition on it, and activate it.  The effect of this is similar to using Windows ReadyBoost on a Windows Vista or Windows 7 system.

Comment: Remember to set the priority higher for the flash memory than your swap partition, or it won't do much.

Comment: If you use a flash drive as swap, you'll destroy the flash drive in a short period of time, possibly weeks or even days.  Flash drives are not good for swap memory as they have a limited number of reads and writes.  Try using an external hard drive instead.

Comment: @ShankarG, I need to disagree with you on several points.  First, flash memory does not have a limited number of reads, but is typically limited to 100,000 (more or less) write cycles per block.  Second, it's unlikely that a system will subject a flash drive being used as swap to thousands of writes a day (as your comment implies). Third, most modern flash drives can wear-level so that no one block receives a disproportionate number of write cycles.  A good-quality flash drive should see about one year of service under typical usage conditions as swap space.

Comment: @ShankarG: (continuation of last comment) Microsoft says that a flash drive being used for ReadyBoost can last about 10 years under typical usage conditions, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomarcher/archive/2006/06/02/615199.aspx.  For more information on using a flash drive as swap, see http://www.symbolengine.com/index.php/2011/01/10/swap-partition-on-a-flash-drive-is-it-really-that-bad/.

Comment: @DragonLord, thanks for the correction regarding reads from flash drives.  But still am skeptical of the flash suggestion. The Microsoft example is moot as, as the FAQ says, ReadyBoost specifically allocates its work to minimise writes - which the Linux kernel will not do when using swap space. The second link you've sent has a good argument but ignores the fact that the minimum block size when writing to flash memory is often very large - so one may be writing ten bytes but have to use a minimum of 128KB. I also know of people who have busted their drives by using them as swap.

Answer (score 3):

If what causes your problems are known processes, you can restrict them using `ulimit`
For example, script the launcher of your app like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -v 1048576
/usr/bin/greedyapp
```

Your app will be able to get only 1 GiB of virtual memory before getting out-of-memory errors. I've tried it with browsers and it will effectively protect your RAM without killing the browser straight away when reaches its limit. But the app may then behave oddly (like stop responding user input), so you may try it first with a very strict limit to see what it does in an out-of-memory. Still, way better than those hd trashes.

Note that `ulimit` only affects the calling process and its childs, setting the limit for all the processes of that branch. I wouldn't recommend to put it in your session script.

Answer (score 1):

DragonLord is correct, the issue is the fact that the OS does not like that your using an excessive amount of RAM. The closer you are to maxing out your RAM. The system will fall into a state where it starts using virtual memory. The faster your harddrive the faster your computer will be when in this state, however there is only so much performance you can gain from that. More RAM is needed in order to stop this from happening.

Clearly you already realize the issue is only when using certain programs, some in which you have created. Due to the information that has been given it is only logical to assume your issue is RAM.